# share data between iOS native app and browser app

Tags: ios

I am a rookie iOS developer trying to figure out this. Pardon me if I am asking basic question.
I need to set an unique identifier in the device (iphone or ipad) that can be read by the app (can be browser app or native app). Is this feasible ?
Reason being: the device needs to be uniquely identified. The user might be able to use the installed app or through browser as well.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTML element containing any amount of content and hide it with CSS. Sometimes I use an 'input' element just for that and read it with javascript. I *think* you use data-uri also.